# Do I need a Ukraine visa as a permanent USA resident?

Tags: visas, ukraine, us-residents, colombian-citizens

I am a permanent resident of USA. I am planning to visit Ukraine for tourism and I will stay for 17 days. Do I need a visa since I am a lawful permanent resident of USA?

Answer (score 2):

The Ukrainian foreign ministry's [visa information page](https://mfa.gov.ua/en/consular-affairs/con/visa) doesn't mention any condition relating to US permanent residents. You will need a visa for this trip **if** people of your nationality require a visa to visit Ukraine.

You've indicated in the comments that you're a Colombian citizen. The [visa requirements for foreigners](https://mfa.gov.ua/en/consular-affairs/entering-ukraine/visa-requirements-for-foreigners) page states for Colombian citizens:

> Visa required except for DP, SP holders.
>
> DP, SP holders may enter and stay in Ukraine without visa for up to 90 days

(DP and SP refer to diplomatic and service passports respectively).

Assuming that you have a standard civilian Colombian passport, you will need a visa.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was trying to search. I am Colombian. residing in USA.

Comment: @Michael I've updated the answer to take that into account - as a Colombian it depends what type of passport you have, but it is likely that you **do** need a visa.

Comment: Colombian citizens can [get an e-visa](http://evisa.mfa.gov.ua/) as late as 10 days before arrival.